# How to get the total length of complete hex file (Both intel and Motorola hex files)?

Tags: java, intel, motorola

i want to get the total length of all data records present in different address records in complete hex file for both Intel and Motorola S19 hex files.

For example,

:020000048000FC

:10246200464C5549442050524F46494C4500464C33

:10247200464C554944ABACDEAF46494C4500464C33

:02000004800AFC

:10246200464C5549442050524F46494C4500464C33

:10247200464C554944ABACDEAF46494C4500464C33

:020000049000FC

:10246200464C5549442050524F46494C4500464C33

:10247200464C554944ABACDEAF46494C4500464C33

:00000001FF

( Please ignore the spaces between records in the above sample hex file).

i have googled for the same but i could not get anything useful.

I am trying to do comparing two hex files. For Comparison, i want to get the length of complete hex file. But i could n't get any idea to get the exact length of complete hex file.

Can anyone pls help me on this ?

Thanks in Advance !

Complete Hex File is defined as :

In case of Intel Hex File, each line is defined as records and it must start with : (colon). It can be address or data records. Hex File can contain any number of Address records. Address records can contain its data records. Each data record having its length specified in first byte after : (colon). 
For more information, please refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX .

I want to calculate the total length of data records in complete hex file. That is, sum of length of all data records present under each corresponding address records in hex file.

Comment: Are each of your `:...` sequences what you call "complete hex files"?

Comment: I have edited the question with defintion of complete hex file. Please check.

Comment: From the Wikipedia article, it looks like Motorola files have a slightly different representation (SREC), is that true according to your experience as well?

Comment: "_Each data record having its length specified in first byte after : (colon)_". You can read the file and add up the value of every byte after a `:` (colon).

Comment: @fge Yes. Motorola hex file having different representation comparing to Intel. Same hex data can be represented in both Intel and Motorola formats.

Comment: I guess, then, what you want is a wrapper class which is able to compare the "binary contents" of each file format, but that will require reading the entire files into memory: is that a problem to you?

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to do comparing two hex files. For Comparison, i want to
>   get the length of complete hex file. But i could n't get any idea to
>   get the exact length of complete hex file.

Why don't you use [`length()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29):

```
File hexFile = new File("/path/to/your/hexfile");
long length = hexFile.length();
```

Comment: In case, two intel hex files having different layout(length of records in hex file) but data is still same, i cannot use length() method. For example, the above same hex data can be generated with layout 0x20, :020000048000FC

:20246200464C5549442050524F46494C4500464C247200464C554944ABACDEAF46494C4500464C33

:02000004800AFC

:20246200464C5549442050524F46494C4500464C247200464C554944ABACDEAF46494C4500464C33

:020000049000FC

:20246200464C5549442050524F46494C4500464C247200464C554944ABACDEAF46494C4500464C33

:00000001FF    i want to compare two hex files having different layouts but same hex data.

Comment: You should create a class to represent the data, and ovveride the `equals()` method. Than you can read your two files, have their data represented in your objects and can compare them with `equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

To determine the size you can use ls -l command. 
For comparison you could use MD5, with produce a hash value.